# How to change the position of the the breadcrumbs using hooks?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am learning Woocommerce. I am on shop page and I have to display the breadcrumbs below the product header. By default it is showing like below image.

[image]

I have to display the below of the header. I want to know that what hook I have to use it.

I tried below

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'woocommerce_show_page_title', 10, 2 );
```

but it's not working even I am also not getting my `home` in the breadcrumbs

Answer (score 1):

You must use the following hooks to display breadcrumb under the archive title:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 15 );
```

If you need to do this on specific pages, you should use [conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/):

```
// just for Shop page
if ( is_shop() && ! is_product_tag() && ! is_product_category() ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 15 );
}
```

Comment: Yes, It's working but is there any option to only change in shop page? Because it's completely removing from single product page.

Comment: Yes, you can use [conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/). I am editing the code.

Comment: I added your updated answer but it's not working

Comment: You have **cache** plugin?

Comment: No, I am not using any plugin for cache. I am checking in private browser. without the conditional tag it does work but with conditional it's not working.

Comment: I added two new conditional tags to `if` statement

Comment: I found the answer. It's working but is it a correct way to do?  add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_template_redirect' );
function custom_template_redirect() {
    if( is_shop() ) :
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 15 );
    endif;    
}

Comment: I tried before but it's was not working then I tried above code in the comment and that is working

Comment: This is about your theme, the default Woocommerce mode works with my code.